# DotNetOpenAuth OAuth2 for Basecamp API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, basecamp

I'm having some difficulties getting the OAuth2 working for the Basecamp API with DotNetOpenAuth, here's what I have so far, this is a ASP.NET MVC 4 web app.

```
public ActionResult Basecamp()
{
    var server = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription();
    server.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new");
    server.TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token");

    var client = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient(
        server, "my-basecamp-id", "my-basecamp-secret");

    client.RequestUserAuthorization(returnTo: new Uri("http://localhost:55321/settings/basecampauth"));
    Response.End();

    return null;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BasecampAuth()
{
    var server = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription();
    server.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new");
    server.TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/token");


    var client = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient(
        server, "my-basecamp-id", "my-basecamp-secret");

    var state = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(Request);
    Response.Write(state.AccessToken);
    Response.End();
    return null;
}
```

The is the error I get from Basecamp:

```
--- 
:error: "Unsupported type: nil. We support user_agent and web_server."
```

I've tried to search and look around, and could not found much interesting. Any help / pointer would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hey Dominic: mate I need some help with basecamp authantication. I'm trying to get login using base camp as MVC project gives use Google facebook etc how can I get log in using my basecamp credentials

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
server.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new");
```

to this:

```
server.AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization/new?type=web_server");
```

Note: i added `type=web_server` to the end of the uri.

Take from [these official docs](https://github.com/37signals/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md).